# How do I find original request path before redirect Express 4

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, httprequest, passport.js

Let's say I am trying to access the path `http://localhost:3000/users#/WyCrYc28r/foo/1414585518343`. 
But the path `/users` needs to be accessed only by the authenticated users as following:

```
  app.get('/users', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
      req.session.user = req.user;
      res.cookie('uid', req.session.passport.user)
          .render('users', { title: 'The Foo Machine', user: req.user });
  });
```

And following is the `isLoggedIn` middleware:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
      return next();
  res.redirect('/login');
}
```

And following is how the `login` is being handled:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/users', 
    failureRedirect: '/login', 
    failureFlash: true 
}));
```

I get redirected to the `http://localhost:3000/users` after logging in, but I want to the user to go to `http://localhost:3000/users#/WyCrYc28r/foo/1414585518343` after successfully logging in as that was where the user wanted to go in the place place.

I am using `PassportJS` module for authentication/authorization here and have the front end developed in `AngularJS`.

Could somebody help me with it?

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two common solutions to this pattern.  Adding the angularjs in there may complicate things a little, but maybe this will get you started:

1)  save the url as a query param in the redirect url

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
  res.redirect('/login?fromUrl='+req.originalUrl);
}
```

then after login you get that value and do the redirect, something like:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login'), { failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true },
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(req.param('fromUrl'));
});
```

2)  (Not as easy or scalable) use your session state to store the from-url.  it might look like:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
  req.session.fromUrl = req.originalUrl;
  res.redirect('/login');
}
```

then after login you get that value and do the redirect, something like:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login'), { failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true },
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(req.session.fromUrl);
});
```

Comment: Hey mattyice, `req.originalUrl` gives me the value `/users` and  later I get a `TypeError: Cannot call method 'param' of null` with the first solution I tried.

Comment: interesting...so in my tests the originalUrl has the hash-suffix so I'm not sure what that is about.  As far as the 'param' part, I'm not that familiar with the passport API, I had to go off of the examples here (http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/).  My example seemed legal but it clearly isnt passing you that request object.  Maybe try removing the second arg "{ failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true }" as a test?

Comment: I moved the middleware `isLoggedIn` at the top and somehow I got the hash part in `/login?fromUrl='+req.originalUrl` for `req.originalUrl`, but it still printed `/users` on the console for `req.originalUrl`. And I am still getting the I get the `TypeError: Cannot call method 'param' of null` error. Removing `{ failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true }` does not make any difference.

Comment: ok, yeah, like i said, i dont know the passport api that well.  all you need to some way to set redirect url from the `req` obj using passport and that part should work.